# Store a image and text from spinner in database in mysql through json in android

Tags: android-spinner

i want to save the image list of images in array from drawable and show in spinner with image and text and save this image and text both in database and retrieve the image and text in list view via JSON web service in mysql database.

Answer (score 0):

Spinners are using adapters. Just make your own adapter, extending `BaseAdapter` or `ArrayAdapter` and specify `getView()` method there to make your own view with text and images.